# transfering variable from angular to c# web api

Tags: c#, angular, post, transfer

I have sending variable with post function

```
  someFunction(param) {
    console.log("someFunction> "+param);
       return this.http.post(appSettings.BackEndUrl + '/test/someFunc',param);     
    }
```

console.log shows

> someFunction > 10

In backend I have

```
public async Task<Object> someFunc(string ttt)
{
    WriteLog("someFunc.txt", "start > "+ttt);
```

In log I see

> start >

even if I change string to int

```
public async Task<Object> someFunc(int ttt)
{
    WriteLog("someFunc.txt", "start > "+ttt);
```

I still see only

> start > 0

How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding it as querystring
Change this way:

```
someFunction(param) {
console.log("someFunction> "+param);
   return this.http.post(appSettings.BackEndUrl + '/test/someFunc?ttt='+param);     
}
```

Comment: u sure ? your answer is Get type not POST.

Answer (score 0):

I am not perfectly sure if this is a .Net feature, but I remember using the `[FromBody]` annotation in front of the parameter you want to get from the body of the request.
In addition your param should have the same name in front- and backend.

In your case it would look something like

```
public async Task<Object> someFunc([FromBody] int param)
```

I personally dont like to add it to your url since with some data you definetly don't want to have it in there.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using ASP.NET Core 2.1+, simply use the [ApiController] attribute to automatically infer the [FromBody] binding source.

Comment: yes it's ASP.NET Core 2.1+ can u wire some example ?

Comment: Just add [ApiController] attribute to your Controller class.

Comment: [ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase

Comment: [ApiController]  is in place. it was there from the beginning

Comment: Check the request content type. It must be 'application/json'